# Has the dual existence of 'Logic' tag (on Maths and Philosophy SE) caused these problems?

Tags: discussion

About my [Logic Area 51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97097/logic?referrer=1u7IMHKJKcLVbTGWoHuajg2), [this post's](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23247/96284) statement of the existence of the Logic tag on Maths and Philosophy SE, implies unfamiliarity with problems that appear evident to me.
I then [commented](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23247/on-topic-at-both-mathematics-se-and-philosophy#comment36842_23247):

> Supporting Premises: 1. With this proposal, most questions on Logic (except ones about Mathematical Logic, which would correctly remain on Math SE) would be located and unified in one place. This unification aids:
>    2. searching,
>   and eliminates:
>   3. cross-posting 4. duplicates 5. indecision and errors of where to post.

Are my premises true or false? I do recognise these premises' impertinence to some Logic questions (eg Mathematical Logic) that are more specific towards Math.

The dual existence of this Tag motivated me to question this also on [Maths Meta SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23434/53259).

Comment: I think it would be a good help for our focus to have another space for pure logic questions

Comment: Do you have any example in mind of a logic question that would not be suitable in phil or math SE?

Answer (score 3):

With reference to your premises,

**Premise 1 does not seem to be true.** Unless SE culls out all philosophy and math problems about logic and moves them to a new logic.SE, then they will not be located in a unified place. Moreover, unless some mechanism is added to move all new questions in math and philosophy that are logic questions to the new SE, the problem will return.

Ergo, 2,3,4 and 5 all also become false.

---

Personally, I think this would *weaken* the philosophy.SE pretty significantly. I say this not because I love every logic question we get or the weekly need to re-explain material implication, but because it seems like many of the people who have academic degrees in philosophy who come here answer logic questions.

Comment: +1. Thanks for your constructive response, due to which I refined premise 1.

Comment: I'm not really seeing how that solves anything. If logic questions other than mathematical logic are all to be kept in one place, then wouldn't the one place be philosophy.SE ? We're not so large that  we need to lose a good %  of our questions (Cf. EL splitting out ELL).

Comment: Yes; the `logic questions other than mathematical logic` could be confined to Philosophy SE then. But what about moving all Logic questions to a separate SE?

Comment: But what would be the benefit of that vs. the current arrangement? Are we so overwhelmed at philosophy.SE that the logic questions are creating an unbearable burden?  Or conversely, should we make a new SE for each individual philosophy tag?

Comment: Sorry if my proposal offends you. If we suppose premise 1, then what about premises 2-5? Would they not benefit?

Comment: It doesn't offend me. I just don't see the benefit of it. If all the logic questions excluding mathematical logic were consolidated in a single place, then 2, 3, and 4 do seem to follow.

Comment: 5, however, does not follow, because the origin of indecision is probably not with where questions belong but with where to post questions. To reword that, your proposal would consolidate where they belong, but it would not make it so that random posters (who perhaps have no experience with SE) would know they should post it at whatever the proper location is... instead, they would post in precisely the places they already do *plus* whatever the new place is.